# Command that reflects the update scenario in the store

Tags: google-play, apk, android-app-bundle, bundletool, apk-signing

How should bundle files be tested at the command line level to most accurately reproduce the scenarios that occur in the Google Play Store?

We use the following command to install the build for the connected device:

```
bundletool-all-1.14.0.jar build-apks -connected-device --bundle=BUILD_NAME.aab --output=APKS_NAME.apks --ks=keystore.jks --ks-pass=pass:password -ks-key-alias=alias --key-pass=pass:password
```

The first installation is done with the command

```
bundletool-all-1.14.0.jar install-apks --apks=APKS_NAME.apks
```

The application update scenario that takes place on the Play Store is crucial for me.

What should the command be that corresponds to the one that is called during the update on the store?

I have searched the Internet for information on the commands used on the Play Store for bundles, documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool, but I have not found a command line command responsible for updating the apk file.

Comment: I am not aware that Google has documented how the update process of an app via PlayStore works. You can just assume that in the update process all changed APK files that belong to your app will be replaced by the updated one. Usually the app processes are terminated before the update.

Comment: Surely there is a command you can use to check this scenario from the command line. It cannot be assumed that the application will run smoothly without the testers checking it beforehand. In the case of many applications, some settings may be overwritten, which can have very negative consequences for the user.

Comment: If you perform some sort of migration on first start after the update is up to the developer. This has nothing to do with how the updates have been installed. So installing an update the way you have shown in your question should be the correct way. The rest is up to the code of your app.

Comment: if you mean bundletool-all-1.14.0.jar install-apks --apks=APKS_NAME.apks
 will only work for newly installed apps. Nothing happens for an existing one. My question is, what command should I use if I already have the application installed and want to upgrade it to a new version...